# How do I fix my Pig Latin encryption code?

Tags: python, indexing

I'm trying to fix the ' if w[0] not in vowel: ' portion of my code (for handling words that start with consonants. BUT the return values are not what they should be and I don't know why!

```
def encrypt(w):
    '''
    encrypt to pig latin
    '''
    Lstw = list(w)
    y = 0
    if w[0:2] == 'qu':
        PLw = []
        for element in vowel:
            #find first occurence of vowel in 'qu...'
            y = w.find(element)
            #if vowel found, y = 0
            if y != -1:
                #terminate loop and continue to line 22
                break
        x = w[0:y]
        PLw.append(w[y:] + '-' + x + 'ay')
        return PLw[0]
    if w[0] in vowel:
        PLw = []
        PLw.append(w + '-way')
        return PLw[0]
    if w[0] not in vowel:
        PLw = []
        for element in vowel:
            v = w.find(element)
            if v != -1:
                break
        PLw.append(w[v:] + '-' + w[0:v] + 'ay')
        return PLw[0]
    else: 
        if w[1] in vowel:    
            PLw = []
            x = w[0]
            PLw.append(w[1:] + '-' + x + 'ay')
            return PLw[0]
```

```
print(encrypt('yesterday'))
print(encrypt('STRENGTH'))
```

should return

```
>>> esterday-yay
>>> ENGTH-STRay
```

Currently returning

```
>>> ay-yesterday
>>> H-STRENGTay
```

Comment: What is `vowel`, and where have you narrowed the problem down to?

Answer (score 0):

I see three bugs right away; there might be more.

1. Your vowel-seeking loop is looking for the first vowel in the vowel list, not the first vowel in the word.
2. I'm guessing your `vowel` list is lowercase-only, which is why it breaks for allcaps input.
3. Your loop that looks for the first vowel doesn't account for the case where there is no vowel at all, which is why the breakage from (2) is not obvious.

Comment: Thank you, I did not account for the uppercase vowels. For whatever reason, though, 'yesterday' does not return the correct value. I believe it's because the first element of vowels is 'a' which is what is found with the w.find() function. Do you by change know how to make it so that the first vowel of the word (e) is found rather than prioritizing the first values of vowels?

Comment: Ah, I misidentified one of your bugs.  Updated.  The bug is that you're looping through the vowel list (`for element in vowel`) and breaking once you find that vowel anywhere in the word -- so you're not looking for the first vowel, you're looking for the first `a`, and then the first `e`, etc.  Maybe it would be better to loop through the word (from start to end) and break at the first vowel?